# What's is the equivalent, by switching dydx to dxdy, of the following conditional probability integral of two continuous random variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, random-variable, integral

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are two continuous random variables and where $f_{Y|x}(x, y)$ is the conditional density function of the two variables when $\{x<y, 0<x<\infty, 0<y<\infty\}$, then:

$$P(0<Y<3|0<X<1)=\int_0^1\int_x^3f_{Y|X}(x,y)dydx$$

What would be the equivalent of the above with $dydx$ switched to be $dxdy$?

My attempt:

$$P(0<Y<3|0<X<1)=\int_0^3\int_0^yf_{Y|X}(x,y)dxdy$$

though this does not give the right answer (since I calculated with the actual function given in the problem).

Comment: My suggestion with these is always to sketch the area out. If you do, you'll see that those areas aren't equivalent. As a hint: you'll have to break the the $dxdy$ integral into a sum of two $dxdy$ integrals.

Comment: @NickKoprowicz Oh I see because for $y > 1$ it would not be from $0$ to $y$ since it stops at $x = 1$. Would it be $\int_0^1 \int_0^y f{Y|x}(x,y)dxdy+\int_1^3 \int_0^1 f{Y|x}(x,y)dxdy$?

Comment: Did you mean to say $0 < y < \infty$ instead of $0 < y < - \infty$?

Comment: @ericperkerson Oh yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral $\int_0^1 \int_x^3 f(x,y) dy dx$ corresponds to this picture, where we integrate along $y$ first from the values $y = x$ to the values $y = 3$.

[image]

The integral $\int_0^3 \int_0^{g(y)} f(x,y) dx dy$ where
$$
g(y) = \begin{cases}
x, & \text{ if } y < 1 \\
1, & \text{ if } y \ge 1
\end{cases}
$$

corresponds to this picture, where we integrate along $x$ first from the values $x = 0$ to the piecewise-defined values $x = g(y)$.

[image]

So you would have to break the integral into two pieces to do the second integral, viz.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^3 \int_0^{g(y)} f(x,y) dx dy & = \int_0^1 \int_0^{g(y)} f(x,y) dx dy + \int_1^3 \int_0^{g(y)} f(x,y) dx dy \\
& = \int_0^1 \int_0^{x} f(x,y) dx dy + \int_1^3 \int_0^{1} f(x,y) dx dy 
\end{align}.
$$